# PHP emails sent to exchange server are split between two addresses

Tags: php, email, exchange-server

I'll try to explain the problem we have at my company the best I can :

So I have several forms across different servers. All are sent up to send emails with the `mail()` function in PHP to the email address **email@ourcompany.fr**

Now I've noticed a weird behavior : when the forms are hosted on our server (I'm talking about our apache server, the mails are handled by an exchange server) they arrive fine at the address up there.
But when the forms are hosted anywhere else on the internet, the emails arrive at the address **email@ourcompany.es**

What could the problem be ? SMTP configuration ? A set of rules at the exchange server ?

I am pretty much a newbie when it comes to emails and how they're handled when they're sent...

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:** As per MarcB recommendation I tried the following in the shell :

```
XXXX:~$ nslookup -type=mx securitasdirect.es
Server:     10.40.144.166
Address:    10.40.144.166#53

securitasdirect.es  mail exchanger = 10 smtp.securitasdirect.es.

XXXX:~$ host -t mx securitasdirect.fr
securitasdirect.fr has no MX record
XXXX:~$ host -t mx securitasdirect.es
securitasdirect.es mail is handled by 10 smtp.securitasdirect.es.
```

Comment: Sounds like a DNS MX record configuration issue, or possibly mail server forwarding rules.  Impossible to tell without more information (the actual domains etc)

Comment: If you had shell access to the various servers, do `nslookup -type=mx ourcompany.fr` or `host -t mx ourcompany.fr` (whichever of those two is installed) to see what server the mails are going to. That's the first step in tracing out out problems like this.

Comment: @Rudu, what more information would you need ?
@Marc B, I'll try that and update my question accordingly.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so based on your update... and running `dig` from my local machine to confirm, your `securitasdirect.fr` domain has no MX records setup on the publicly accessible DNS servers.

Internally in your network, it's possible (likely even) you use different DNS servers which have MX records and hence internally you can deliver email to `@fr` while externally it's not working.

**Update** not sure if you're changing things as I write this answer, but it seems like I'm now getting a valid MX return for `securitasdirect.fr`.

Beyond that, `securitasdirect.fr` fails the rDNS test (see: http://www.mxtoolbox.com) while `securitasdirect.es` passes.  It's possible this is also interfering with mail delivery.

Comment: Because the only people with access to the inner workings are in Spain, I'll try to put them in the right direction and hopefully they'll get what's going on ! Thanks for your answer it's been very helpful. Cheers